# Get exponential value using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like this:

```
strings s = "1.0E-20"
```

Is there a way to get only -20 from this using regex? 
I tried this:

```
(([1-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([1-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([1-9]+))([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

this gets me e-20 in group5 but still not just -20.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to use a regex.. This is not readable compared to a simple substring solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex for dealing with text, use Math(s) for dealing with numbers:

```
Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble("1.0E-20")) // returns -20
```

To make sure your string input is a valid `double` use `TryParse`:

```
double d, result = 0.0;
if (Double.TryParse("1.0E-20", out d))
{
    result = Math.Log10(d);
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Also, if you want to get the `1.0` (multiplier) from your input:

```
var d = Convert.ToDouble("1.0E-20");

var exponent = Math.Log10(d);

var multiplier = d / exponent;
```

Comment: quick question for you. How can i make sure i dont get out of bound error using this? Or get NaN value?

Comment: You could always use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the initial `double` before using the `Math.Log10`.

Comment: Got the answer if anyone else needs it: !Double.IsNaN(Math.Log10(Convert.ToDouble(val)))

Answer (score 1):

You can do that **without Regex** like:

```
string s = "1.0E-20";
string newStr = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('E') + 1);
```

Later you can parse the string to number like:

```
int number;
if (!int.TryParse(newStr, out number))
{
    //invalid number
}
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

You can also use `string.Split` like:

```
string numberString = s.Split('E')[1]; //gives "-20"
```

Its better if you add check for string/array length when access `string.Substring` or accessing element `1` after split.

Comment: @Servy, I am extracting `-20` and then doing the parsing on that. `s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('E') + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

No need for `Regex` when `string` methods can do wonders

```
string str = "1.0E-20";
str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('E') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = str.IndexOf("E") != -1 ? str.Substring(str.IndexOf("E") + 1) : "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions to achieve this, you should switch up your capture groups.

```
(([1-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([1-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([1-9]+))([eE])([-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

Group 6 will contain -20 with your given example with the regular expression above. Note how the parentheses have moved. We might need more information from you though. Do you have any more sample data? What's the end goal here?